# Trace of involution is the dimension of the space implies it is the identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, involutions

I was trying to write explicitly a linear automorphism $\phi$ on a 2-dimensional vector space $V$. I knew that $\phi^2=Id$ and $\text{Tr } \phi=2$. Using the matrix representation
$\phi=\begin{pmatrix} a& b\\ c& d \end{pmatrix}$, I got the system of equations
\begin{align}
&a^2+bc=1\\
&ab+bd=0\\
&ac+dc=0\\
&bc+d^2=1\\
&a+b=2.
\end{align}
From this it is easy to see that only solution is $\phi=Id$. But now I ask wether we could prove this fact without working out a matrix, I mean, in a more elegant way? Also, does this extend to other dimensions; i.e. if $V$ is finite dimensional and $\phi\in\text{Aut}(V)$ is an involution whose trace equals $\text{dim }V$, then $\phi=Id$?

Comment: Yes, and again yes.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Second yes is wrong if the hypothesis is still $Tr \phi =2$. Second yes is true if the hypothesis is $Tr\phi =n$.

Comment: @JerryCastilla For larger dimensions, what is your hypothesis regarding the trace?

Comment: The hypothesis is stated in the question, in the last paragraph. Anyway, it is $Tr \phi=dim V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know what is your background  in linear algebra.

But you could say:

- As $\phi^2 =Id$, the minimal polynomial of $\phi$ is  either $x-1$, in which case $\phi$ is the identity or $x^2-1$.
- In later case, the minimal polynomial has simple roots, so $\phi$ is diagonalizable.
- $\phi$ being diagonalizable is similar to a diagonal matrix having $1$ and $-1$ for only possible values on the diagonal.
- As its trace is equal to $2$, the only option is that all values on the diagonal are equal to $1$.
- So $\phi$ is similar to the identity.
- But the only endomorphism similar to the identity is the identity itself.

Finally, the identity is the only solution to the problem in dimension two.

For other dimensions, a similar approach proves that the identity is also the only solution, supposing that $Tr \phi = \dim V$.

Comment: Thanks for you very well explained answer. The sum of the values on the diagonal is dim $V$ by hypothesis, not 2.

Comment: @JerryCastilla In that case the identity is the only option.